# stratify argument in train_test_split vs StratifiedShuffleSplit

Tags: scikit-learn, train-test-split

What is the difference between using the `stratify` argument in `train_test_split` function of sklearn, and the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` function? Don't they do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two modules perform different operations.

`train_test_split`, as its name clearly implies, is used for splitting the data in a single training & single test subset, and the `stratify` argument permits doing this in a stratified way.

`StratifiedShuffleSplit`, on the other hand, provides splits for cross-validation; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html):

> Stratified ShuffleSplit cross-validator
>
> Provides train/test indices to split data in train/test **sets**.

Notice the plural *sets* (emphasis mine).

So, `StratifiedShuffleSplit` is there to be used instead of [`KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) when we want to ensure the CV splits are stratified, and not to replace `train_test_split`.

Comment: If you set `n_splits=1` on the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` then I would expect same split as `train_test_split` with `stratify` if same `random_state` but I am getting different results. Any idea why?

Comment: @LazyEval No; please open a new question on this.

Comment: Have you tried making sure all the arguments are the same? Such as the test_size / train_size as well? Because technically using a random_state should return you the same values.